# Prompting User For Instructions

Tags: c++

I am trying to write an infix calculator and I want to start the program off asking the user if he/she needs help or not. I have written the code that will offer instructions if the user inputs 'y' or 'n', however, in both cases, the program ends without allowing the user to enter an infix expression and running the rest of the program. It seems as though the program is breaking in main right after cout << "Expression?"; It does not give the option for the user to input anything after that.

Comment: You're never calling `isValidResponse`, you're just testing whether its address is not null.

Comment: Ahhh you're right! in provideHelpIfNecessary(void) I changed it to: while(true) {                                                           if (isValidResponse(help) && (isYesResponse(help)) but it is still breaking out of the program early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `cin >> help`, you're only reading one character, the `y` or `n`. The newline after that is left in the input buffer.

Then when the main function uses `getline`, it reads up to the next newline, which is the one that was left in the buffer by `provideHelpIfNecessary`. So it just reads a zero-length line, and that causes the `while` loop to `break`.

Use `getline` in `provideHelpIfNecessary` instad of reading just one character.

Comment: would it be as simple as saying getline(cin, help) in provideHelpIfNecessary? Because when I do that I receive a nasty error stating: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
  getline(cin, help);

Comment: You need to change `help` from a `char` to a `std::string`.